# Python: Unable to install as a module but a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

As I need to run python with specifying a module, but not to run the install package as the executable, I tried to install the package locally,
but it does not install as a module but as a package for some reason.

Here is the series of commands what I did.

```sh
# enable virtualenv 
# now, no external pip package is installed 
$ . ./venv02/bin/activate

# install the module 
$ pip install mitmproxy

# I thought this should be worked, but it does not. 
$ python -m mitmproxy --mode upstream:https://localhost:3148 --listen-port 8085 --scripts ./mitmproxy_main.py
/home/user/pg/python/venv02/bin/python: No module named mitmproxy.__main__; 'mitmproxy' is a package and cannot be directly executed

# but as a package I can run 
# but this is not what I desire, 
# since in the later step I need to use the "module" mitmproxy in vscode launch.json to debug the python script ./mitmproxy_main.py. 
$ mitmproxy --mode upstream:https://localhost:3148 --listen-port 8085 --scripts ./mitmproxy_main.py
```

The virtualenv Python version and pip version is as follows.

```sh
(venv02) user@pc:~/pg/python$ python --version
Python 3.6.12
(venv02) user@pc:~/pg/python$ pip --version
pip 21.2.4 from /home/user/pg/python/venv02/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

So How can I install a "module" locally to run `python -m [module]`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know, to install python packages locally :

```
for python 3: pip3 install --user <package>
```

Also try doing :

```
pip3 install <your_python_module_name> -t lib/
```